# Bad JSON formatting in Jupyter API PUT call - error 400

Tags: python, json, api, jupyter-notebook, put

I am quite new in python and can't understand why I am getting this 400 error. It seems like JSON formatting is wrong in the PUT call.

I have this dataframe.

[image]

And I am trying to run this code

```
url = "https://api.name.com/pacing-strategy"

for row in df_call_put.itertuples():
    qs_li_id = {'line_item_id':row.line_item_id, 'member_id':1111}
    payload_li_ps = [{'line_item_id':row.line_item_id,
                      'pacing_strategies': 
                          [{'strategy_type': 'intelligent',
                            'when': 'ALWAYS'}]}]
    rs_li_ps = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload_li_ps) ,headers=headers, params=qs_li_id)
```

It should be just fine (exactly formatted like other PUT call I use) but it returns "

> 'errorCode': 400, 'errorDescription': 'Parameter line_item_id is invalid.'

As a comparison I ran the exact same thing in postman and it works fine, I however need it in a script so I have to use it in Jupyter.

One lead that could help you to find the solution. In Terminal I managed to make it work switching code from

```
curl -b cookies -c cookies -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @always_asap.json "https://api.name.com/pacing-strategy?line_item_id=12345678"`
```

to

```
curl -b cookies -c cookies  -X PUT  -d @always_asap.json 'https://api.name.com/pacing-strategy?line_item_id=12345678&member_id=1111'
```

So it seems like the JSON reformatting with Content type was the issue.

Thanks!

I tried to remove `json.dumps` in the PUT call

I tried to change `payload_li_ps` code removing `[]` at the beginning.

We should get a OK status 200 but we have a 400 error

Comment: Can you show the contents of `always_asap.json`?

Comment: if you have `line_item_id` in the URL parameters, I don't think it should also be in the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar
[
  {
    "line_item_id": 13604488,
    "pacing_strategies": [
      {
        "strategy_type": “intelligent”,
        "when": "always"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: the documentation put also line_item_id in the JSON and it worked in postman. Thanks for your help

Comment: The only possible problem I can think of is that `row.line_item_id` is a string rather than an integer. If you do `print(payload_li_ps)` is it quoted?

Comment: If the `curl` command works, you can just put it in the notebook with an exclamation point in front of it. You can even assign the output to a variable with something like `a = !curl ..`. (Variable `a` will actually be a [IPython.utils.text.SList](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.text.html#IPython.utils.text.SList) type object, and so you need to use `a.n` to get the string of the content.) If you know the system will always have curl or it's just for you/troubleshooting, it's an alternative to keep in mind. The pure Python will indeed be more portable.

Comment: Thanks Barmar & Wayne, the issue was actually coming from the headers with my connection token that had bad formatting. Nothing related to the code.